# Add Virtual Folder to all urls (Apache)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Using Apache and .htaccess how can I do the following:

Redirect all urls to include a fake folder.
For example:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/example.php
http://example.com/folder/example.php
```

redirect to:

```
http://example.com/fakefolder/
http://example.com/fakefolder/example.php
http://example.com/fakefolder/folder/example.php
```

fakefolder does not actually exist in the server directories so I also need to point `http://example.com/fakefolder/` to `http://example.com/`.

So basically if the user goes to `http://example.com/` I want the url to show `http://example.com/fakefolder/` but at the same time still point to `http://example.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use in your `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+fakefolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /fakefolder%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L] 

RewriteRule ^fakefolder(/.*)$ $1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thubms up for the croises's ans!